# Swagger-ui config overwrite

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, swagger, kubernetes-helm

I have swagger running on my k8 cluster. I'm trying to override the default petshop url with environment variables in my deployment.yaml. This works well with a URL. Only when I try with two URLs as the swagger documentation indicates does it go wrong. Then swagger somehow tries to put a comma after the last url.

```
    env:
    - name: URLS
      value: "https://example1.local/v3/api-docs,https://example2.local/v3/apidocs"
```

The swagger-initialiser.json converts it to:

```
urls: https://example1.local/v3/api-docs,https://example2.local/v3/apidocs,
```

Can't see how to fix it. Can anyone help me out? :)